# Favicon in Angular not showing

Tags: angular, favicon

Ive been struggeling to get my favicon in my Angular app to show up. No matter what i try, it wont work.

[I have it in the src folder of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWVAh.png)

And this is how i linked it in the index.html:

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="~/myicon.ico">
```

Id be very gratefull, if someone could help me out.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

Static resources are kept under `assets` folder of the angular application, try getting `favicon` from the assets folder by pointing path there.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/assets/myicon.ico">
```

Make sure, you have a below code `assets` array in `angular.json` which make sure to copy assets folder content to final build.

```
"assets": [
   "src/assets"
],
```

Comment: Ok so ive put the icon there and changed the import line and now i get 404 not found when i open the developer tools in chrome.

Any ideas on why thats happening?

Comment: It should work, can you please rerun angular application?

Comment: Now a favicon is showing, but its the standard Angualar one and not my custom one.

Comment: okay, can you please make sure you have kept your `myicon.ico` file under `my-project/src/assets` folder?

Comment: yes its still there.

Comment: Can you please `Ctrl + F5` (Hard Refresh) page?, it could be cache thats causing this issue.

Comment: Still not showing up and now i also get a 404 for the picture i had in the header. This is starting to get very strange haha.